# Difference between "from x.y import z" and "import x.y.z as z"

Tags: python, python-import

In situations where you want to import a nested module into your namespace, I've always written it like this:

```py
from concurrent import futures
```

However, I recently realized that this can be expressed using the "as" syntax as well. See the following:

```py
import concurrent.futures as futures
```

Which has the subjective advantage of looking more similar to other imports:

```py
import sys
import os
import concurrent.futures as futures
```

... with the disadvantage of added verbosity.

Is there a functional difference between the two, or is one officially preferred in a PEP or otherwise?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['import module' or 'from module import'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710551/import-module-or-from-module-import)

Comment: @chrisz: That covers the difference between `import module` and `from module import thing`; it doesn't cover `import module.thing as thing`.

Comment: Note that `import foo.bar as bar` only works if `foo.bar` is itself a module, while `from foo import bar` works for *any* module-level name in `foo`.

Comment: the `as` was created to avoid the collision between modules/libs/funcs  with same name, an alternative namespace....

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710551/use-import-module-or-from-module-import and I got the question in a review audit :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few functional differences. First, as already mentioned in the comments, `import package.thing as thing` requires `thing` to be a module (or a subpackage, which is not actually a separate case because packages count as modules).

Second, in Python 3.5 and later, if `from package import thing` finds that the module object for `package` does not have a `thing` attribute, it will try to look up `sys.modules['package.thing']` as a fallback. [This was added](https://bugs.python.org/issue17636) to handle certain cases of circular relative imports. `import package.thing as thing` does not yet perform this handling, but it [will](https://bugs.python.org/issue30024) in Python 3.7.

Answer (score -1):

```
import concurrent.futures as futures
```

Allows you to reference the module under the `futures` namespace in your code (as opposed to `concurrent.futures` without the `as` syntax). However, the typing is mostly redundant--you're importing something and declaring its name to be the exact same thing. The standard syntax for this type of import is the `from <package> import <module>`.

The salient point about your question is that the `as` syntax is mainly to support multiple imports of the same name without clobbering each other. For example.

```
from concurrent import futures
from other.module import futures as my_futures
```

Anything else and you are abusing the `as` syntax and to me would be considered anti-pattern, because the language provided you a correct way to do what you wanted.

Comment: The `as` is not strictly redundant in that example because without the `as`, `concurrent` is introduced in the namespace, not `futures`.

Comment: Not true. When you `import concurrent.futures` you need to address it as `conncurrent.futures`. When you `import concurrent.futures as futures` you address it as `futures`.