# Python: import foo.bar as bar vs from foo import bar

Tags: python, python-import

Given that `foo.bar` is a module, what is the difference between

```
import foo.bar as bar
```

and

```
from foo import bar
```

I'm particularly interested in what lazy importing of modules does to this.

*Note:* This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710551/use-import-module-or-from-module-import).

Comment: For whoever finds this question, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61472248/5976530) answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the first code line:

```
 import foo.bar as bar
```

Here you are importing `bar` from `foo` package but why added  `as bar` means when you need to access any function `func` in that `bar`. You have to access like
`foo.bar.func` but when you added `as bar` you just use

```
 bar.func
```

The same to the line `from foo import bar` just importing the `bar`

Comment: I don't think that's true. Trying both, and using `dir()` and `dir(bar)` to check, the namespaces look identical. Functions within `bar` are available in both.

Comment: @SimonFraser: My explanation mean the accessibility of functions in a module

Comment: In both examples a function `func1` in bar is accessible with `bar.func1()`

Comment: As @SimonFraser says, these are completely equivalent when you're using them.  I want to know if there is any difference to what Python does with loading imports