# In python, what is the difference between 'import foo.bar as bar' and 'from foo import bar'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I see this convention in pyTorch and matplotlib:

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Is there a reason why the whole path (`module.submodule`) is being imported as an alias instead of just the submodule? What is the difference if I import like this:

```
from torch import nn
from torch import optim

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

*Edit*: So for the generic case:

```
import foo.bar as bar    # [1]
from foo import bar      # [2]
```

Can there exist code which refers to `bar` such that it will run with `[1]` and not `[2]` (and vice versa)? I.e. is there *functional* difference between these two ways to import?

Comment: For the examples listed, probably not much difference. The place where I see `as` used is when you want a shorter name to use. The most common example would be `import numpy as np`, although your example of `plt` is common too.

Comment: Somewhat related - while the syntax `import torch.nn as nn` is similar to the re-export rules defined under PEP-0484, it in fact is not considered valid as `torch.nn` differ from `nn`.  In order to make this a valid strict re-export under that pep the syntax must be `from torch import nn as nn`.  Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73712178/) for further details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Behind the scenes, all of the import statements are essentially mapped to the builtin `__import__` eg:

```
import torch.nn as nn
```

becomes

```
nn = __import__("torch.nn", globals(), locals(), [], 0)
```

similarly:

```
from torch import nn
```

becomes

```
nn = __import__("torch", globals(), locals(), ["nn"], 0).nn
```

As for `matplotlib`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# becomes
plt = __import__("matplotlib.pyplot", globals(), locals(), [], 0)

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
# becomes
plt = __import__("matplotlib", globals(), locals(), ['pyplot'], 0).pyplot
```

Subtly different but functionally equivalent.

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__