# Python "import foo.bar as baz" vs "from foo import bar as baz"

Tags: python, python-import

Is there a difference between these two imports, or are they just syntax sugar for the same thing?

```
import foo.bar as baz 
# vs
from foo import bar as baz
```

I tried both, and the results of

```
>>> baz
```

and

```
>>> dir(baz)
```

look identical for each.

Comment: IMO it's not "syntactic sugar" so much as two statements that produce the same effect through slightly different paths.  `3 + 1` isn't syntactic sugar for `2 + 2`.

Comment: Related: [In python, what is the difference between 'import foo.bar as bar' and 'from foo import bar'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61471924/11082165)

Comment: While the second syntax `from foo import bar as baz` can function as re-export of `bar` as `baz`, it does not in fact make it a valid strict re-export under the rules defined under PEP-0484 as the symbol `baz` differ from `bar`.  Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73712178/) for further details about this distinction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`import foo.bar as baz` requires `foo.bar` to be a module. It's not an expression that performs attribute lookup, but a single dotted name. (Most importantly, there's no guarantee that any package exposes the modules in the package as attributes. `import foo` does not guaranteed that `foo.bar` evaluates to the module `bar` contained in `foo`.)

`from foo import bar as baz` lets `bar` be any attribute exported by the module `foo`: `bar` could be a submodule, or a class, or any other global variable defined in `foo`.

(This is one reason why `import` is a statement, and not just a function call. If it were a function, you would have to write `import('foo.bar')` to ensure that `foo.bar` is not interpreted as an expression before `import` is even called.)