# What is memory and performance difference between importing all the functions of a given module and only those functions which we need?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, memory-management

For example  `import math`  import's all function in math module whereas if we write  `from math import sqrt,pow`  then only `sqrt(),pow()` are imported.

Is their any performance or memory difference in both of them.

Comment: If Python is designed properly, there shouldn't be any difference.

Comment: Have you run any tests to check the performance in each case?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). Even if there's a difference, it will usually be negligible, so only worry about this when you actually have a performance problem.

Comment: Welcome Hansie, If your question is unclear you will get downvoted and maybe put on [hold] until you refine your question. 
You can avoid downvotes by temporarily deleting the question, editing it into shape and undeleting afterwards. You question is speculative at best and hence off-topic - you might want to review [ask] and [help/on-topic] to make your questions better. Did you _observere and measure_ distinct differences between one and the other? This findings (and the [mcve] to reproduce it) might make this a better question.

Comment: Dupe:  [use-import-module-or-from-module-import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710551/use-import-module-or-from-module-import)

Comment: @PatrickArtner  "If your question is unclear you will get downvoted" What is not clear in my question to you ?

Comment: @Hansi it is not clear that you "encountered" any problems with it - you did no testing or measuring. You did not import every module possible and look at the memory footprint of your python process when executing your code. The question itself is answered in the dupe (and there are several others on SO) hence it is unclear if you did any reasearch on this topic or if you simply placed to Question here to let the community brain solve it for you.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Thanks.I got the point.This was my first question.Next time i will come with some research and provide its details .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For example `import math` import's all function in math module whereas if we write `from math import sqrt,pow` then only `sqrt(),pow()` are imported.

It's a bit more complicated than that.

If we ignore for a moment that the `math` is built in into the interpreter (so there's nothing that has to be actually loaded), whether you do `import math`, `from math import sqrt, pow` or `from math import *`, the whole `math` module is loaded anyhow, and, after the import statement, it is present in `sys.modules`. So, it's not like there's more or less work to do *for loading* depending from how you import it.

The only difference between these constructs is the creation, in the import scope, of references to the names you mention in the import statement.

`import math` is probably the cheapest statement *by itself*, as it loads the module and just adds a local reference to the module object in the current scope; it essentially boils down to doing

```
math = __import__('math')
```

However, each usage is going to be more costly, as `math.sin` will need two dict lookups (one `LOAD_GLOBAL` and one `LOAD_ATTR`) if the `import` was at global scope, or one local variable lookup (`LOAD_FAST`) + one dict lookup (`LOAD_ATTR`) (if it was imported locally to a function) to actually reach the function object to invoke.

`from math import sqrt, pow` will cost a bit more, as it needs to load the module, look up `sqrt` and `pow` in it (two dict lookups) and create the corresponding entries in the scope where you imported them (two dict assignment if in global scope, two `STORE_FAST` local assignments if in function scope). It is equivalent to something like:

```
__temp = __import__('math')
sqrt = __temp.sqrt
pow = __temp.pow
del __temp
```

(`__temp` does not really exist, it's going to be just an object on the stack; `sqrt` and `pow` will be locals or globals depending from where the `import` statement has been issued)

On the other hand, on lookup this is going to be faster, as it needs only one dict lookup (`LOAD_GLOBAL` for global import) or one local lookup (`LOAD_FAST` for import local to a function) compared to the two above.

`from math import *` is the same as above, but for all the symbols provided in the module `__all__` list (or all the symbols provided by the module period if no `__all__` is specified).

From a memory standpoint, the latter two are going to cost more than the first, as they create more entries in the locals list or in the globals dict.

That being said, this kind of consideration is generally completely irrelevant, as we are talking about extremely small differences; what matters most when deciding how to import is how much pollution to your namespace is fine to allow in the name of less typing/less explicit imports.

Instead, the kind of optimization in these matters that usually counts is to bind frequently called functions to local variables to avoid continuous lookups in inner loops; for example

```
import math

def plot_it(framebuffer):
    sin = math.sin
    cos = math.cos
    for y in range(1024):
        for x in range(1024):
            framebuffer[y][x] = int(127*(sin(x)+cos(2*y)))
```

is generally going to be faster than doing `math.sin` and `math.cos` at each iteration, or even than importing `sin` and `cos` at top level in the file and using them straight inside the loop, as they are respectively two or one dict lookup away (to be done at each iteration), while here the interpreter just has to load two locals in the inner loop (which is very fast, it's just a straight array load).