# What is really being imported?

Tags: python, import, module

I'm getting a bit confused by how `import` works in Python (3.5). I thought that using something like "import x" would be just as writing whatever is written into "x.py", however it does not seem like it.

I have the following structure:

- main.py
- Package1

  - module1.py

Now, just for completion, the module is:

```py
## module1.py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot(x,y):
    A = plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.show()
    return A
```

So it really doesn't do anything that `matplotlib.pyplot` would not do. Now my main.py is just calling it like this:

```py
## main.py
from Package1.module1 import plot
a= plot([1,2,3],[2,4,6])
```

And this works. So I'm assuming that it actually imports `matplotlib.pyplot` as plt, since otherwise the function `plot` would not work. However, if now I add anything to `main.py` such as `plt.figure()` or `np.array()`, it says that it does not recognize these.

So the actual question is... Have I imported `matplotlib.pyplot` to the main namespace? If not, is there a different namespace here? If there is, if I now wanted to use `matplotlib` in the `main.py` below that code, and I imported it again with `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`, would I be importing it twice?

I am a bit lost in the hierarchy here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use 'import module' or 'from module import'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710551/use-import-module-or-from-module-import)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from Package1.module1 import plot
```

When you do this, only the name `plot` from the module `Package1.module1` is pulled into your current module (`main.py`). The other symbols that may be defined in `Package1.module1` are not pulled in.

But.

The whole module in `Pacakge1.module1` is run. If you put a `print('something')` in the global part of the module like:

```
## module1.py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print('something')

def plot(x,y):
    A = plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.show()
    return A
```

It will be printed.

```
something
```

So your function definition is indeed loaded into the runtime. Hence your function works. But you only have access to the function that you imported i.e. `plot` and not anything else.

Comment: Oh. I see. However, If I import "all" using `import Package1.module1` in `main.py`, it still does not recognize `plt` nor `np`. And then the imports would be run twice in main if I add them, right?

Comment: Python will cache imports. So not exactly. Those t hings will be imported only once.

Comment: I see. Just one last thing. If I use `import Package1.module1 as alias`, I can then use `alias.plt.figure()` and it works. However, if I use `import Package1.module1`, without an alias, it does not let me use `Package1.module1.plt.figure()`. Is there another way to call the inner imports?

Comment: Using `__all__` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834/can-someone-explain-all-in-python

Comment: I see. Thank you very much, kind sir/madam :)