# Python import error when package is being imported

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have a strange (for me) problem with python imports and I would like to understand what is wrong with it.

I have created a demo project with the following directory structure:

```
├── entry.py
└── foo
    ├── __init__.py
    └── bar
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── sdk.py
        ├── service.py
        └── utils.py
```

If I run `python entry.py`, in `service.py` the following statement works:

```
from foo.bar import utils
```

while this does not:

```
import foo.bar.utils as utils
```

```
# entry.py:

from foo.bar.sdk import get_sdk
print(get_sdk())

# foo - __init__.py
# empty on purpose

# bar - __init__.py
from .service import Service

# sdk.py
def get_sdk():
    return "SDK"

# service.py
import foo.bar.utils as utils # wrong import
# from foo.bar import utils # works!
class Service:
    def do_service(self):
        util = utils.get_utility_string()
        print("Doing service call {}".format(util))

# utils.py
def get_utility_string():
    return "This is useful"
```

By running `python entry.py` I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "entry.py", line 1, in <module>
    from foo.bar.sdk import get_sdk
  File "/Users/paloand/Downloads/p_demo/foo/bar/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .service import Service
  File "/Users/paloand/Downloads/p_demo/foo/bar/service.py", line 1, in <module>
    import foo.bar.utils as utils
AttributeError: module 'foo' has no attribute 'bar'
```

From my understanding in `entry.py` when the `get_sdk` symbol is getting imoprted from `sdk` module, `foo` package is being imported as well. While importing `foo` in `bar` the `__init__.py` file requests the import of the `Service` symbol. So while `foo` is being imported it is required again in `service.py`.

Link to the uploaded demo project in my Dropbox: [Demo](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ozwvol07kc3sl8f/p_demo.zip?dl=0)

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710551/use-import-module-or-from-module-import) question and all the answer but there I could not extract any information there. I also found this [bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue992389) but I am not sure if it applies here. I read also the [common traps](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html) of import in python but could not find this one.

I want to understand the difference and what is really happening.

I am using **python 3.6**

Thank you

**EDIT**

Updated with error message

**EDIT 2**

I have tried `python -vv entry.py` in both cases. The relevant logs are in the paste: https://pastebin.com/J9guMqJS.

In both cases the import order is the same, in the "bad" case this import  fails:

```
import 'foo.bar.utils' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x1103ddf28>
```

Comment: This issue has been fixed in [Python 3.7](https://bugs.python.org/issue30024).

Comment: Thank you that explains my problem!