# What is the effect of 'from x import variable' in python3

Tags: python, variables, scope

I am feeling particularly thick today.  Consider

mod1.py

```
count = 0

def foo ():
    global count
    count = count + 1
```

mod2.py

```
import mod1

from mod1 import foo, count

print("mod1.count = ", mod1.count)
print("count = ", count)

foo()

print("mod1.count = ", mod1.count)
print("count = ", count)
```

I assumed the import of count into mod2 effectively globalized it.

```
> python3 mod2.py
mod1.count =  0
count      =  0
mod1.count =  1
count      =  0
```

I've obviously got some fundamental misunderstanding.  I assumed the import would essentially make mod1.count and count aliases, but that is not the case.  I am guessing this has to to with using both 'import' and 'from-import'.

Comment: Related: [Use 'import module' or 'from module import'?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19185936/1898437)

Answer (score 1):

The difference between them is probably usability.

```py
import module
```

lets you access a method from the module using the `.` operator. while

```py
from module import something
```

lets you use `something` without referring to the module using `.` operator.
You can also say that it lets you use `something` globally.

Using the `from` methode you will have imported `something` globally. That doesn't mean that `something` from the `module` has vanished. It's just making new instances of the methods.
so when you import both the `module` and the instance of `something`, you can literally access `something` either way (with or without using the `.` operator).

Comment: But in his example, he's getting the variable in the module using the `.` operator, even though he used `from module import variable`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've pretty much answered your own question. They are not aliases, but two distinct objects, presumably because they exist in different namespaces. You can verify this more simply by doing your imports then `print(mod1.count is count)`. This would return `True` if they were aliases.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the way Python handles the names of variables. In order to have some basis for the explanation, I extended your example with a list as a second imported variable:

mod1.py

```
count = 0
lst = [1, 2, 3]

def update_count():
    global count
    count = count + 1

def update_lst():
    lst.append(4)
```

test.py

```
import mod1

from mod1 import count, lst, update_count, update_lst

print("mod1.count = ", mod1.count)
print("count = ", count)
print("mod1.lst = ", mod1.lst)
print("lst = ", lst)

update_count()
update_lst()
print('\nAfter updates: \n')

print("mod1.count = ", mod1.count)
print("count = ", count)
print("mod1.lst = ", mod1.lst)
print("lst = ", lst)
```

Output:

```
mod1.count =  0
count =  0
mod1.lst =  [1, 2, 3]
lst =  [1, 2, 3]

After updates: 

mod1.count =  1
count =  0
mod1.lst =  [1, 2, 3, 4]
lst =  [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

So, what happened?

When you import `count` and `lst`, these new names are created in the namespace of your script. The name `count` is another name for the integer object `0` already referred to by `mod1.count`, and the name `lst` is another name for the list already referred to by `mod1.lst`.

When we execute the updates, the list gets updated in the module, but it remains the same object: `mod1.lst` and `lst` still refer to the same object.

Things are different for `mod1.count`, as we make this name refer to a new object, the integer `1`, in  `count = count + 1`. 
Now, `mod1.count` refers to the integer object `1`, while `count` in the main script still refers to the original `0` object.

So, that's all just normal Python names behaviour.

If you haven't read it yet, I recommend Ned Batchelder's classic [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) that explains very well how names work in Python.