# How to use a Python module's functions inside a function you're defining WITHOUT importing beyond your function's scope (Ie: R has package::function)

Tags: r, python-3.x, function, import, scope

Is there a way to incorporate **`Python` functions from an external module/library** in a function you're writing/defining, **without importing them globally or beyond of the function scope**?

For example, in `R` you can do `package::function`:

```
myfxn <- function(x){           # R example
  dplyr::as_tibble(x)
}
```

I'd like to do something similar in Python, but as far as I can tell, people usually just import the modules/elements of modules at the top of the file (for speed, succinctness, comprehensiveness, etc.) I know you can technically do something like this:

Example of what I know you can do in Python (but isn't what I'm looking for):

```
def myfxn(x):                   # Python
    from pandas import DataFrame 
    return(DataFrame(x))
```

...But what I'd really like is a way to use a function like the `pandas` `DataFrame` one without having to globally import it. I wish there was something like...

```
def myfxn(x):                   # Python
    return(pandas.DataFrame(x))
```

Where I wouldn't have to actually *import* anything. Is there any way of doing what I'm referencing? If not, is there an argument (except for a tiny amount of processing speed) about why there shouldn't be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use 'import module' or 'from module import'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710551/use-import-module-or-from-module-import)

Comment: I read through that post and a bunch of others. None of them encompass my question

Comment: `import pandas` then `pandas.DataFrame()`. I'm very sure the link answered all your questions. You need to read carefully.