# Python Import Performance - Module vs Function From Module

Tags: python, performance, import

Why does importing the entire module take less time than importing only one function?

```
%%timeit
import pid
```

**269 ns ± 47.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)**

```
%%timeit
from pid import PidFile
```

**1.77 µs ± 175 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)**

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710551/use-import-module-or-from-module-import