# Are the following `import` statements equivalent: `import mypack.mymod` and `from mypack import mymod` in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Are the following `import` statements equivalent: `import mypack.mymod` and `from mypack import mymod` in Python3?

Suppose I've the following directory directory hierarchy:

```
.
├── main.py
└── mypack
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
    │   └── mymod.cpython-37.pyc
    └── mymod.py
```

When importing the `mymod` module in `main.py` are the `import mypack.mymod` and `from mypack import mymod` statements equivalent? I've been experimenting with both, and they seem to perform the exact same job.

Comment: They import the same module, but they import it under different names into your script…!

Comment: What do you mean by equivalent? It should be immediately observable that they bind the module to a different name, thereby not being equivalent.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use 'import module' or 'from module import'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710551/use-import-module-or-from-module-import)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difference is w.r.t how package is available to use in your `main.py`. Let's take the three possible ways:

> assume dir structure is same as yours and `foo` function is present in `mymod.py`

---

## case 1:

```
# main.py
from mypack import mymod
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(dir())
    mymod.foo()
```

This results in

```
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'mymod']
bar
```

---

## case 2:

```
# main.py
import mypack.mymod
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(dir())
    mypack.mymod.foo()
```

This results in

```
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'mypack']
bar
```

---

## case 3:

```
# main.py
import mypack.mymod as md
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(dir())
    md.foo()
```

This results in

```
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'md']
bar
```

---

#### Observation:

As you can see when `dirs` is printed, the module in case 1 is available as `mymod` & thus you use `foo` as `mymod.foo`, in case 2 as `mypack` & thus to use `foo` you now have to use `mypack.mymod.foo` and last in case 3 as `md` & this to use `foo` you now have to use `md.foo`

Answer (score 1):

The two statements import the same module, but make it accessible through different identifiers. I will give examples using the `os.path` module:

```
import os.path

# Try accessing os.path.realpath
try:
    rp = os.path.realpath(".")
except NameError:
    print("!! Cannot access os.path")
else:
    print("OK", rp)

# Try accessing path.realpath
try:
    rp = path.realpath(".")
except NameError:
    print("!! Cannot access path")
else:
    print("OK", rp)
```

This yields:

```
OK C:\Users\ME\Documents
!! Cannot access path
```

Change the `import` in the first line to:

```
from os import path
```

And the output switches to:

```
!! Cannot access os.path
OK C:\Users\ME\Documents
```