# python 3 import all package vs one part

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I was reading on the difference between `from … import` vs `import ...` in python 3.6.
after multiple search I can't find any answer to my specific question.

Look at the following example:

```
from urllib import request

import urllib
```

1) Are they equal? I suppose from the basic meaning in English language that the first one imports only `request` and the seconds imports everything inside `urllib` including `request` and many others. Am I right?

2) I 1 is true, suppose my python program uses only `request` from `urllib` would their be any performance advantages on using the first instead of the second?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use 'import module' or 'from module import'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710551/use-import-module-or-from-module-import)

Comment: @MayankPorwal what about performance? I didn't get an answer for that yet

Answer (score 5):

It almost entirely depends on context, style guide (for example the [google style guide defines this](http://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#23-packages)), and developer but there are some guidelines I personally follow.

1. If the name of the functions you are importing can have more than 1 meaning, use a `import module` style. For example if a module has a name like `select()` this can mean many things. If it comes from a sql library it may be a select statement, i've also seen the same name used in libraries that take user input etc. Basically follow the [Zen of python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#id2)

   > Explicit is better than implicit
2. If there is more than one usage of the same name in your dependencies/standard library. For example in both the `math` and `secrets` module have a function caalled choice, but only the one in the `secrets` module is designed to be used in cryptography so it's better to `import secrets` and use `secrets.choice` or `math.choice` instead so you know which you are using.
3. If you (or your team) use different terminology, it can be better to do `from module import function as blah`. So long as this terminology is consistent this can be a good way to organize your imports. For example if your team always refers to `random.randint` as `randy` you can do `from random import randint as randy` (this is a bad example, it's just what I thought of off the top of my head), though this means anyone outside your organization will not understand necessarily what the code does.
4. DO NOT USE `from module import *` this is always a terrible idea as it brings in EVERYTHING and can cause name collisions with in-file functions.
5. If libraries have names you want to use built in then using `from module import blah` can be useful to avoid naming collisions.
6. This is a somewhat padantic point, and honestly unless you are importing a ridiculous number of things it doesn't matter but importing select functions is actually faster because of how python initializes interpreter sessions. This only matters on MASSIVE scale though.

I could go on for ages, but as @[Mayank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5820814/mayank-porwal) mentioned there is already another good answer posted here: [Use 'import module' or 'from module import'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710551/use-import-module-or-from-module-import)

Answer (score 1):

When using `import urllib` Will import every method inside of the urllib package but you will have to call it as so:

```
urllib.request.urlopen('http://python.org/') as response:
```

which means for each method you will want to use you will have to call the package name. However when using `from urllib import request` you can use the method directly as so:

```
request.urlopen('http://python.org/') as response:
```

The best practice is to import only the methods since when you do a blind import you are essentially adding a lot of overhead to your code that is not needed. But it does not really matter which method you choose.