# Math module sqrt function python

Tags: python, sqrt

I was exploring through the maths function in python 3.0. I have written the following code for the following question. I am not sure if the answer is right. 
Write a code segment that only imports `sqrt` from the `math` module. 
The code then prints out the square root for 81 and 9 respectively using the `sqrt` function `math.sqrt(81)`

```
from math import.sqrt(81)
print(sqrt(81))
```

Please help me to rectify if not please post the solution for the question thanks

Comment: Note that the `math` module is spelled without capital.

Answer (score 2):

You can either import the whole package as `import math` and do `math.sqrt(81)`. But since you only need `sqrt()` function from math, you can just import that `from math import sqrt`

```
from math import sqrt
print('Square root of 81 is: ',sqrt(81))
```

Answer (score 0):

To import a specific function from a module, do something like

```
from math import sqrt
```

Then you can call the function as

```
print(sqrt(81))
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710551/use-import-module-or-from-module-import) is an informative discussion on this topic for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

It's almost right:

The way you import a module (which you can think of as a bundle of a lot of functions) is the `import` function e.g if you want to import the entire math module you write `import math`.
Now if you want to use `sqrt` from Math you can do `math.sqrt(81)`  but it might be annoying to write `math` all the time, thus you can just import the function by

`from math import sqrt`

and that way you can call it without writing `math` first such as

`print(sqrt(81))`.

EDIT:

Changed `Math` to `math`

Comment: true, should've been `from math` but that could be corrected (a typo) instead of down voting.

Answer (score 0):

Python have multiple simple ways to do,

```
from math import sqrt
print(sqrt(81))
```

If you don't want to use mat library, 
simply

```
print(81**.5) # used for square root

print(9**2)  # Used for squre the number
```