# How is "from" in python can copies

Tags: python, c++11

How is the (**from**) in python can take a copies variables from one file to another, and what happened if the variables is the same name ? [image: Description my Question]

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/710603/8840245) to question [Use 'import module' or 'from module import'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710551/use-import-module-or-from-module-import) should provide guidance to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That description is not quite right. Module variables are names bound to objects. When you

```
import somemodule
```

two things happen: 1) the module is imported into python, if it isn't imported already, and 2) a variable called `somemodule` is created and bound to that module.

When you

```
from somemodule import foo
```

Its similar. The module is imported but instead of binding `somemodule` to your module's namespace, a variable called `foo` is created and the object in `somemodule.foo` is bound to it. You added a reference to the object in `somemodule.foo`, but you didn't copy it.

When you reference `foo`, you get the same object that was in `somemodule.foo`. But if either of these variables are rebound to new objects, the other variable still holds a reference to the old object. Now the two variables reference different things.

Notice that this redefinition only happens if the variable is rebound (reassigned) to a new object. A list append doesn't rebind the variable. But something like `foo = 1` does. And sometimes you just kinda have to know what happens. `+=` on a list doesn't rebind a new object, but the same operation on an integer does. Beware augmented operations like that if you `from x import y`.

Its generally safe to `from x import y` functions, classes and other modules because its unlikely that those will be reassigned in the original module. Otherwise, buyer be ware.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, when you do `from module import variable`, the variable "variable" in your program is defined to be however the variable is defined in the module so you can use it. However, this might cause existing variables and functions to be overwritten.