# What is the difference between "Import PIL" and "from PIL import Image"?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, attributeerror

I am copying a code from online example how to search the resolution of an image.

```
import PIL
batman = PIL.Image.open("image.jpg")
batmobile, batplane = batman.size
print(batmobile,"x",batplane)
```

There is attributeError. PIL has no attribute name 'Image'.

```
from PIL import Image
batman = Image.open"image.jpg")
```

If I changed like this, the code can run perfectly. So, I used `print(dir(PIL))` to see attributes. There is no 'Image' attribute. I don't understand.

```
import datetime
batman = datetime.datetime.now()
```

is the same as

```
from datetime import datetime
batman = datetime.now()
```

right?
I downloaded 'pillow' with pip.

Comment: The answer is already here: [Use 'import module' or 'from module import'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710551/use-import-module-or-from-module-import)

Comment: I guess you mean `batman = Image.open("image.jpg")`? Opening an image with PIL works fine like `im= PIL.Image.open(i)` where `i` is the full path to the image file. In the case of a png file `im` is then an object `PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

from PIL import Image is required to work with pillow (>=1.0),

you can also try using import Image directly, and it would lead to an error due to the updates.

and regarding your directory query, look into the pillow ( fork of PIL ) and it should result to your satisfaction, as the documentation includes the image module, only the access for pillow (> 1.0), does not support import Image but uses the syntax from PIL import Image.

Refer to official Pillow documentation for more.

Comment: It would be helpful to provide the documentations you are referring to.

Comment: Pillow documentation, link : https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Answer (score 0):

```
import module_name
```

This will import all the functions in that module.

```
from module_name import function_name
```

This will only import a specific function from the module.

Comment: The first one will import the module, not the *objects* inside.

Comment: yeah. But did the first 'import PIL' only program do some mistakes? Please, point my mistake, so I can avoid it.

Comment: You import specific things to improve your runtime. It is correct if you have to use more than one function in your code but if you only need 1 function is it better to import that specific function.

Answer (score 0):

example :

```
import leaf
environment = leaf.tree("Oxygen")
```

if you import everything or that specific function from an import, you don't need to mention the function again

```
from leaf import *
environment = tree("Oxygen")
```

or

```
from leaf import tree
environment = tree("Oxygen")
```