# Python contextmanager

Tags: python

[image]

I wrote this code
What is the difference between `import contextlib` and `from contextlib import contextmanager` in the link:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html

I'm so confused...

Comment: ```import ....``` imports the whole library where as ```from ... import ...``` imports a specific class

Comment: Then is it okay to use anything on the code I made?

Answer (score 1):

`What is the difference between "import contextlib" and "from contextlib import contextmanager"`

In a way there is no difference: the last name is the name of a variable that python creates for you which it has assigned to something in a different python module.

In the first case: `import contextlib`, you get the variable `contextlib` which happens to be a module and to access anything from it you have to use that name followed by a `.`: `@contextlib.contextmanager`

In the second case: `from contextlib import contextmanager`, you get the variable `contextmanager` which happens to be a class that you can access directly by using its name: `@contextmanager`

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of information in the Internet. I suppose that you can google more proper and deeper information to answer your question by your own than you can receive here.

For example, there is a good question about difference between `import module` and `from module import something` in Python. You can read it [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710551/use-import-module-or-from-module-import)

Also you can check [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/187403/import-module-vs-from-module-import-function) and [this](http://www.wellho.com/mouth/418_Difference-between-import-and-from-in-Python.html) to know more.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll make more effortㅜㅜ