# “from module import *” VS “import module”

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module

### `from module import *` VS `import module`

#### What I know

I know the difference between the 2, the difference is when you are using `from module import *`, you can just refer the classes, functions etc. in the module just like they are defined in the file they are imported in itself.

But when you are just using`import module`, you have to use `module.` before the name of the object to refer it.

#### The problem

So what I don’t know is why is it sometimes considered bad practice to use `from module import *` instead of `import module`?

Comment: Only import what you need: [use-import-module-or-from-module-import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710551/use-import-module-or-from-module-import) - doing the * import clutters your namespace. In your kitchen, do you prefer a drawer that contains pots, another drawer that contains knifes and forks and spoons and a drawer that contains cling film (urks) etc. or do you want to have a wild assortment of knifes, cling film, pots, forks and spoons flying around. With imports it is even more so: there may be name collisions if you just throw all of them inside your namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) states that

> Wildcard imports (`from <module> import *`) should be avoided, as they
> make it unclear which names are present in the namespace, confusing
> both readers and many automated tools. There is one defensible use
> case for a wildcard import, which is to republish an internal
> interface as part of a public API (for example, overwriting a pure
> Python implementation of an interface with the definitions from an
> optional accelerator module and exactly which definitions will be
> overwritten isn't known in advance).