# python running other python files

Tags: python

You can get variables by:

```
from <file> import <var/class/function>
```

but it does not read the entire file.

```
import <file>
```

then what?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use 'import module' or 'from module import'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710551/use-import-module-or-from-module-import)

Comment: show some code, error. also try from file import *