# Python - Importing Libraries Properly

Tags: python, python-import

Question.

I am a noob, what is the difference between this:

```
import selenium
```

And this

```
from selenium import webdriver.
```

Doesn't `import selenium` automatically `import webdriver`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use 'import module' or 'from module import'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710551/use-import-module-or-from-module-import)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does but the use is different.

When you type `from selenium import webdriver` you can access it by typing `webdriver` in your code.

But when you run `import selenium` you can access `webdriver` by typing `selenium.webdriver`.

Sometimes you want to make clear where this function is from like in django urls I always type `from . import views` so I can then type `views.myfunction` in code.

Answer (score 2):

For `import selenium`, names are accessed via `selenium.nameX`. You also have access to the entire selenium package.

With `from selenium import webdriver`, you are importing only webdriver from the selenium package. You do not have access to the entire selenium package. In the second case, you also access names from webdriver via `webdriver.nameX`, not `selenium.webdriver.nameX`.

Answer (score 1):

yes but if you just import selenium you would have to do `selenium.webdriver.functionyouwant` instead of just `webdriver.functionyouwant`

Answer (score 1):

When you type `import package`, you can access `module` by typing `package.module`.

When you type `from package import module`, you can access `module` by typing `module` and you can't use other modules in package `package`.