# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'data_management' in PyCharm

Tags: python

In github there are four py Data which I put on my PyCharm. When I run main.py I get this message:

```
/Users/Armut/Desktop/High_D/Coursera/bin/python /Users/Armut/Desktop/High_D/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Armut/Desktop/High_D/main.py", line 6, in <module>
    from data_management.read_csv import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'data_management'
```

Here is a screenshots:

[image]

Can someone help, what I am doing wrong or how can I fix it?

**EDIT** (Put folders):

```
/Users/Armut/Desktop/High_D/Coursera/bin/python /Users/Armut/Desktop/High_D/main.py
WARNING:root:Failed to import geometry msgs in rigid_transformations.py.
WARNING:root:Failed to import ros dependencies in rigid_transforms.py
WARNING:root:autolab_core not installed as catkin package, RigidTransform ros methods will be unavailable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Armut/Desktop/High_D/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    from visualization.visualize_frame import VisualizationPlot
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'visualization.visualize_frame'
```

[image]

**EDIT**:

```
/Users/Armut/Desktop/High_D/Coursera/bin/python /Users/Armut/Desktop/High_D/src/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Armut/Desktop/High_D/src/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    from src.visualization.visualize_frame import VisualizationPlot
  File "/Users/Armut/Desktop/High_D/src/visualization/visualize_frame.py", line 10, in <module>
    from utils.plot_utils import DiscreteSlider
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils.plot_utils'
```

[image]

**Edit** (No errors, but I just get a blank picture):

[image]

**Edit** (I installed matplotlib 3.0.3 and got this):
The issue here is, that it is just a picture. If you can see there are buttons like "next". I should be able to click it so I can track it. But how does it work?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do the following

```
from read_csv import *
import visualize_frame as vf
```

The reason why it was not working for you is because you were importing files that dont exist on your system. When you do `from data_management.read_csv import *`, what you are telling the Python interpreter to do is to search for a folder called `data_management` inside you're `Coursera` folder and get everything from `read_csv.py`.

This is the same case with `visualize_frame`. Since you have a flat directory structure, you dont need the folder names. You can directly import the `.py` files as is.

Another thing to note here is that I personally wouldn't do `from read_csv import *` because I will be flooding my namespace with a lot of things I probably wont use. I would rather use `import read_csv as any_alias_you_like`. This way I only fill my namespace with what I want by doing the following

```
x = any_alias_you_like.function_call()
```

The reason why I didn't do this with the main code solution is because I am not sure where all you are using `read_csv` functions and classes in your code and if that is not accounted for by prefxing the alias name properly, you will run into a multiple errors. So my advice is to identify all the funcutions/classes that you are using in `read_csv.py` and prefix them properly with an alias.

I also used the `import` statement for the `visualize_frame` differently. This is because, when you do a `from import...`, you are only partially initializing the module. However, a proper `import visualize_frame` will ensure that your entire module is initialized in one call and you can use everything it offers by simply prefixing the alias.

Read about the difference between `from import` and `import...` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710551/use-import-module-or-from-module-import).

Read about how Python searches for libraries [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sys-path-in-python/#:%7E:text=path-,sys.,among%20its%20built%2Din%20modules).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just put folders in it because in github there are also folders. I do not really understand the code... I just want to try to run it because I need it.
Here is the github Link:
https://github.com/RobertKrajewski/highD-dataset/tree/master/Python/src

Comment: Ok, so, you will have to change your directory structure. Create a new folder called `src` inside the `HighD` folder and copy the folders you just created for `data_management`, `utils` and `visualize` into it. Also copy the `main.py` file and paste it into `src`. Now when you open `src`, you should see 3 folders and a `.py` file. After that, go back one step to the `HighD` folder, and create another folder called `data`. This means that your `HighD` folder will now have 3 folders called `Coursera`, `data` and `src`. Put your `.csv` inside the `data` folder and then run `main.py`

Comment: I did but unfortunately there is the next error..

Comment: Ok. Inside the `visualize_frame.py` file, change `from utils.plot_utils import DiscreteSlider` to `from src.utils.plot_utils import DiscreteSlider`

Comment: Thanks a lot, you help me so much. It is not over but I get a picture at least.
https://github.com/RobertKrajewski/highD-dataset/issues/11
Here is someone that had the same issue like me. If you scroll down she said, that it works for her when she "created a new virtual env with the following packages:..."
How can I do that? Is there also a folder which I need to change?

Comment: It's my pleasure to help :)
Do not manually create a folder. Goto this [link](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/). Follow the steps in this to create a virtual environment for your project. Make sure your `env` folder is in `./HighD` and not `./HighD/src`. After this copy all the dependencies the lady on GitHub provided and name the file `requirements.txt`. Keep the `requirements.txt` file inside `HighD`. After this goto the part of the document linked above that says `Using requirements files` and follow the instructions provided.

Comment: Things to note, if you accidentally created the `env` folder in `./HighD/src`, do not cut and paste it in `./HighD`. Delete the `env` folder and recreate it from scratch with the proper path. Follow this [link](https://www.lifewire.com/open-command-prompt-in-a-folder-5185505) and goto the section titled `How Do I Open a Terminal Window in a Folder?` for setting your cmd prompt to the path to the root folder correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244659/discussion-between-lihka-nonem-and-yokanishaa).