# How to pass arguments between python program and a script and then back to program

Tags: python

I am a beginner -- I am trying to write a Main py program that references a py script, passing data arguments to the Script; and then, receiving back data from the Script. What follows is my initial code (that does NOT work) -- your help will be very much appreciated. Thank U.

**main.py**

1. ## Main Program
2. import scriptNo1
3. import sys
4. print("Start Main program")
5. arg1 = 3
6. arg2 = 5
7. scriptNo1[arg1, arg2]
8. sys.argv = ['scriptNo1.py', 'arg1', 'arg2']
9. val1 = scriptNo1.passBackVal
10. print(arg1, arg2, val1)
11. print("The end")
12. quit()

**scriptNo1.py**

1. ## Script Program to be used by Main Program
2. import sys
3. print("Start Script program")
4. passBackVal = arg1 + arg2
5. print("passBackVal in script is: ", passBackVal)
6. print("End of Script program")

Comment: I have a question: why don't you create a method in scriptNo1.py and import it inside main.py? That way, you can call it with the args you want.

Comment: You have taught me something new -- I have NO awareness of Methods --something new to learn. Thank U

Answer (score 0):

An idea:

```
#main.py
from scriptNo1 import func
import sys
ans = func(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
print(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], ans)

#scriptNo1.py
def func(a, b):
    return a + b
```

Is it what you want?

Comment: will this work if you are expecting MULTIPLE returns; e.g., a+b and a/b and a*b?

Comment: No, but you can create one function for each operation and call them accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This is my final outcome (Thank U @Paulo and @Tomerikoo):

```
# main.py
import scriptNo1
from scriptNo1 import funcNo1
arg1 = 3
arg2 = 5
argv = []
argv.append(arg1)
argv.append(arg2)
ans = func(argv[0], argv[1])
print(argv[0], argv[1], ans)
quit()
```

and

```
# scriptNo1.py
def funcNo1(a, b):
    x = a + b
    y = "cat"
    z = 123.456
    passBackVal = [x, y, z]
    return passBackVal
```

Comment: That is a very strange use of `sys.argv`. It is meant to be used for command line arguments. If you use it like that, why not just use a list? Or not use it at all? Just do `ans = func(arg1, arg2)`

Comment: Thank U @Tomerikoo -- when you are a beginner (like I am) the comments from experts are VERY valuable. The recommendation is being implemented. Thank U.

Comment: No problem at all. As I said before, note that the list is not very necessary in this case. Any instance of `argv[0]` can be replaced with `arg1` and any instance of `argv[1]` can be replaced with `arg2`. The list just takes up unnecessary memory. Another comment, you should only use one kind of import: either do `import script` and then call the function `script.func(...)` ; or `from script import func` and then just `func(...)`.  See [Use 'import module' or 'from module import'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/710551/6045800) for more