# difference between from <package_name> import <module_name> vs import <package_name>.<module_name> in the __init__ file of a package

Tags: python-3.9

Is there a difference between these 3 methods to import a module in the *__init__.py* file of a package?
Assuming that the *module.py* and the *__init__.py* are in the same directory and I am importing the package in my program as `import package`

```
import package.module
from package import module
from . import module
```

I did all of them and apparently, all worked with the same results.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use 'import module' or 'from module import'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710551/use-import-module-or-from-module-import)

Comment: @Tzane No, it was about importing modules in the main program but mine is about importing the modules in the _\_\_init.py\_\__ of a package.

Comment: Import statements work exactly the same in module files and \_\_init\_\_.py files

Comment: @Tzane Thank you, but I did not find my answer in the mentioned question, since my question is specifically about packages.